# Cutting atlas into separate PNGs to save them locally

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm looking for a way to target Textures/Sprites from an atlas to save them individually. I've made a script that takes all the Texture2d items from the project and saves them as PNGs but I don't know how to get the individual Sprites from an atlas to save those as separate PNGs too.

In the Project tab I can see all the sprites that are inside of the atlas. Can I target those sprites in code to save those?

EDIT:

I have gotten closer to solving my problem. I search all the sprites in the scene with this code:

```
guids = AssetDatabase.FindAssets ("t:Sprite", null);
```

Then when I export I can get the number of sprites in total judging by the size of `guids`.
To test I've created a button that creates GameObject's and adds a SpriteRenderer to them with the sprite taken from the `guids`. Like this:

```
foreach ( string guid in guids)
{
    string itemName = AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(guid);

    Sprite s = Resources.LoadAssetAtPath<Sprite> ( itemName ) as Sprite;

    var go = new GameObject();
    var spriteRenderer = go.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>() as SpriteRenderer;
    spriteRenderer.sprite = s;
}
```

As expected all the sprites are added. But if I try to save them taking their Texture, I get the whole texture as an atlas again, not the part I'm interested in.

So I decided to make a new Texture2d that I'd export. In that new Texture2d I want to make the size equal to the size of the target sprite (that works) and copy the pixels from the bounds of the sprite (stuck here). I don't know how to actually get the offset and bound for each sprite. Non of the methods in the Sprite class seem to help with that.

So now I'm wondering how can I copy the pixels of a Sprite from it's bounds and not the whole Atlas that it has.

Comment: Do you have the coordinates and size of sprites that are inside atlas as a `.xml` or `.json` file?

Comment: No,  I believe  it's automatically cut by Unity.

Comment: If you knew the coordinates that would be easy to use [ReadPixels](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.ReadPixels.html) and [SetPixel](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixel.html), otherwise you can write an editor tool maybe to input custom coordinates?